# jQuery Nested Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

Excuses if this has been posted, not sure how to search for such a thing.

I'm working on a website and I'd like to know what current industry conventions are. I am more concerned if there is a reason to avoid calling a method inside of another method.

Below I've placed a few examples, please let me know which one is best.

First, easy example on two lines:

```
var formattedRole = HTMLheaderRole.replace("%data%", bio.role);
$("#header").prepend(formattedRole);
```

What about all on one line?

```
$("#header").prepend(HTMLheaderRole.replace("%data%", bio.role));
```

Let's get a little more complicated:

```
var formattedEmployer = HTMLworkEmployer.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].employer);
var formattedTitle = HTMLworkTitle.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].title);
var formattedConcat = formattedEmployer.concat(formattedTitle);
$(".work-entry:last").append(formattedConcat);
```

How about just condensing one of those lines?

```
var formattedEmployer = HTMLworkEmployer.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].employer);
var formattedTitle = HTMLworkTitle.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].title);
$(".work-entry:last").append(formattedEmployer.concat(formattedTitle));
```

Thanks tons for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, avoiding the extra variable assignments in both of the first examples is slightly more efficient. However, the amount of resources saved is so trivial that you would have to be running the function thousands of times on a particularly old mobile device to see and difference. That said, readability is king when comparing two segments of code that have nearly identical performance. Choose whichever option is easier for you or some other maintainer to read.